# How to disable the maximize button of browser in C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem that I want to disable the maximize button of the browser when we run our web application, means user can not maximize the same browser screen in which site is running. I don't know how it will be achieved? Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a better idea to make your site usable with the browser maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, max button of a window is enabled, but if you open as pop-up and pass some value as the window property in that case the max button might be disabled, please see below way to do this job:

Set window `resizable` property as either `no` or `0`.

Format:

```
window.open("pageurl","PopupWindow","resizable=no"); //OR: resizable=0
```

Examples:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com","PopupWindow","resizable=0");
window.open("http://domainname.com/somepage.ext","PopupWindow","resizable=0");
window.open("http://domainname.com/somepage.ext","PopupWindow","resizable=no");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-load the window that way using [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) (javascript)

```
<script>
     function openWithoutResize(url,target) {
          window.open(url,target,"resizable=0");
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to open your target page in a popup window with the resizable attribute set to "no." This cannot be modified on the active page. You will be required to launch a popup window in order to disable maximize. For instance:

```
function onReady() {
    window.open("http://www.contoso.com","myWindow","resizable=no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onresize="window.resizeTo(350,530)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
</form>
</body>
```